# Netcat to automate SpeedTouch administration

Tags: router, telnet, netcat

I figured out how to enable/disable my wireless connection with telnet, but I want to automate it.

I read telnet is not suitable for this, and one should use netcat instead.

This is what I have:

```
nc 192.168.1.254 23 << EOF
username
password
:wireless ifconfig state=$1
EOF
```

But when I run that I get something like:

```
????????Username : Administratorfietspomp:wireless i
```

Some searching turned up the -t and -i options, but neither help very much.

**update**

Expect it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set force_conservative 0  ;# set to 1 to force conservative mode even if
              ;# script wasn't run conservatively originally
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}

if { [lindex $argv 0] == 1} {
    set status "enabled"
} else {
    set status "disabled"
}

set timeout -1
spawn telnet 192.168.1.254
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Username : "
send -- "username\r"
expect -exact "Password : "
send -- "password\r"
expect -exact "_{Administrator}=>"
send -- ":wireless ifconfig state=$status\r"
expect *
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Can't help with the netcat script but this would be pretty trivial to do with expect.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/92736/send-login-credentials-and-commands-using-shell-script-via-telnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `autoexpect`. If you don't have that command already, install package `expect`.

Then just enter `autoexpect` and hit enter. Whatever you enter next will be saved as `script.exp`. When you are finished, hit `Ctrl+d`.

Finally you can run the automated version with `expect ./script.exp`. Of course you can rename the script.exp and move it wherever you want.

Comment: Any idea how to get `autoexpect` on Mac? DuckGo turned up nothing. `expect` is installed though, so I could try to write it by hand.

Comment: Does this ancient link help you? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/418636?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: No, some idiot redirected the page to his Linkedin profile, and I can't find the Tcl folder on my Mac.